# Reinstalling conda_python2 / conda_python3 kernel on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kernel, jupyter, conda, amazon-sagemaker

I've encountered a weird issue. My conda_python2 and conda_python3 in AWS Sagemaker are giving weird results, deviating to a large extent from what I had got earlier. Also, the output is getting generated much slower than usual. I guess the kernel is broken. Can someone please guide me on how to reset the kernel / reinstall it? Thanks in advance!